# Añadir campo nuevo al depends (TypeError: compute_profit_margin() missing 1 required positional argument: 'product_uom_qty')

Tags: python, odoo

La cosa es que en el siguiente código tengo que añadir un campo, en el que se modifica la cantidad de un producto, que multiplique al profit_amount y añadir ese campo nuevo al depends:

```
    @api.depends('price_unit',
             'product_id',
             'product_id.categ_id',
             'product_id.procure_price',
             'product_id.no_calculate_sale_margin',
             'product_id.default_sale_margin',
             'product_id.categ_id.no_calculate_sale_margin',
             'product_id.categ_id.default_sale_margin',)
             
def compute_profit_margin(self, product_uom_qty):
    for line in self:
        price_unit = line.price_unit
        product_procure_price = line.product_id.procure_price
        if price_unit and product_procure_price:
            profit_margin = line.get_profit_margin(price_unit, product_procure_price)
            profit_amount = line.get_profit_amount(price_unit, product_procure_price)
            if line.profit_margin != profit_margin:
                line.profit_margin = profit_margin
            if line.profit_amount != profit_amount:
                line.profit_amount = profit_amount
```

Yo lo añado de esta manera:

```
    @api.depends('price_unit',
             'product_id',
             'product_id.categ_id',
             'product_id.procure_price',
             'product_id.no_calculate_sale_margin',
             'product_id.default_sale_margin',
             'product_id.categ_id.no_calculate_sale_margin',
             'product_id.categ_id.default_sale_margin',
             'product_uom_qty')
             
def compute_profit_margin(self, product_uom_qty):
    for line in self:
        price_unit = line.price_unit
        product_procure_price = line.product_id.procure_price
        if price_unit and product_procure_price:
            profit_margin = line.get_profit_margin(price_unit, product_procure_price)
            profit_amount = (line.get_profit_amount(price_unit, product_procure_price)) * product_uom_qty
            if line.profit_margin != profit_margin:
                line.profit_margin = profit_margin
            if line.profit_amount != profit_amount:
                line.profit_amount = profit_amount
```

Me actualiza el modulo sin problema alguno pero a la hora de cambiar la cantidad del producto me sale el siguiente error:

> TypeError: compute_profit_margin() missing 1 required positional argument: 'product_uom_qty'